# whole div is deleting instead of image

Tags: javascript

```
if(count($father1)!=0) { 
            for($i=0;$i<count($father1);$i++) { 
                if($father1[$i][ 'sbs_f_userid']==$id) { 
                    $pc_pic=$father1[$i][ 'sbs_f_face']. '.'.$father1[$i][ 'sbs_f_format']; 
                    echo '<div class="fpic"><img src="'.$img_loc.'del-but.png" class="myfamily29 dpic f" alt="Click to Delete" title="Click to Delete"/><div class="kpic f"><img src="'.$img_gearup.$pc_pic. '" width="47" height="47" ></div></div>';
?>
```

I am using this code in my programm . The class **FPIC** makes a box which has brown border and it has a father pic  and **del-but.png** image . so when the user click on the del-but.png , then below process runs .

```
$(".dpic").click(function () {

                                if ($(this).hasClass("f")) {q = father ; var ddpic = $(this).parent('div').find(".kpic").find("img").attr("src"); var that = $(this).parent('.fpic');}
                                    lbox = new LadduBox();
                                    lbox.init({
                                                "width": 485,
                                                "height": 232,
                                                "HTML": '<div style="width:488px; height:235px; background:url('+img_loc+'bg4.png) no-repeat;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="488" height="152" style="font-family:arial; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:#ffffff;"><tr><td align="right" height="50" valign="top" colspan="2"></td></tr><tr><td align="center">Are you sure you want to delete the picture?</td></tr><tr><td align="center"><div class=" abc yes">YES</div><div class="no" id="btnClose">NO</div></td></tr></table></div>',
                                                'btnCloseId': '#btnClose'
                                    });
                                    lbox.fire();
                                    $(".abc").bind("click", function () {
                                            $.blockUI({ message: '<h3>deleting...</h3>', css: {
                                                    border: 'none',
                                                    padding: '15px',
                                                    'z-index': '1991000',
                                                    background:  'url('+img_loc+'bg4.png)',
                                                                 '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                                                                 '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                                                    color: '#fff'
                                            }
                                            });
                                    $.post("delete_pic.php", {
                                            "ddpic": ddpic,
                                            "user": q,
                                            "uid": sbs.userid
                                    }, function (data) {
                                    if (data.result == "1") {
                                        if( q == "kid"){ $(".kidd").find("img").attr('src',''+img_loc+'blank_face.png');}
                                            if( q == "mother"){ $(".mat").find("img").attr('src',''+img_loc+'blank_face.png');}
                                                if( q == "father"){ $(".fat").find("img").attr('src',''+img_loc+'blank_face.png');}
                                    }
                                                    that.remove();
                                                    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 100); 
                                    }, "json");
                                    lbox.closeladdubox();
                                    });
                    });  
                    }
    });
```

after the user click , it will ask u ARE U SURE U WANT TO DEL ? if the user click on the yes button then the whole class **FPIC** is removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whole `div` is deleting because you have defined that to be

```
var that = $(this).parent('.fpic'); // i.e. <div class="fpic">
```

And then in the second script you are doing

```
that.remove();
```

To remove each and every image inside:

`that.find('img').remove()`

**UPDATE**

After removing, to add a new image. You have to do this:

`that.append('<img src="path\to\image.png" />');`

In short you have to do this:

```
that.find('img').remove() // remove all the images inside
that.append('<img src="path\to\image.png" />'); // add a new image
```

Comment: but if i need to remove the image only den wat will i do

Comment: Then you may try `that.find('img').remove()`

Comment: @PHP_USER1 if you want to replace that image with some other image then you may want to try `replaceWith()` http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: the problem is that , i have two images ie fatherpic and del-but.png , when i am using ur code , it will change the both the images
can i remove the both the images and then place a new pic ??

Comment: @PHP_USER1  I have updated my answer, please check that

Answer (score 3):

```
var that = $(this).parent('.fpic');
```

`that` is pointing to the parent , not to the image.

and you are doing

`that.remove();` which will remove the `fpic` class

You have to

`that.find('img').remove();`

to replace image , you can do

`that.find('img').attr('src',srcOfAnImage);` instead of `.remove()`

Comment: but if i need to remove the image only den wat will i do

Comment: thnks a lot and if after removing i want to replace it wid another image

Comment: the problem is that , i have two images ie fatherpic and del-but.png , when i am using  ur code , it will change the both the images

Comment: can i remove the both the images and then place a new pic ??